# How to properly schedule multiple local notifications with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Habit-Tracker that lets the user specify up to 7 times per day on which he wants to get notified. In case the user wants to do this every day, that would make 49 scheduled Notifications for a single Habit and I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do it.

I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

This is my current code :

```
  Future<void> scheduleWeeklyHabitNotifications(Habit habit) async {
    for (int weekDay in habit.scheduledWeekDays) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          0,
          'Its time for ${habit.title}',
          'weekly scheduled notification body',
          _nextInstanceOfDayAndTime(weekDay, 20, 30),
          const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'weekly notification channel id',
                'weekly notification channel name',
                'weekly notificationdescription'),
          ),
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime);
    }
  }

  tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTime(int hour, int minutes) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate =
        tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minutes);

    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }

  tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfDayAndTime(int weekDay, int hour, int minute) {
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = _nextInstanceOfTime(hour, minute);
    while (scheduledDate.weekday != weekDay) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }
```

so this code is working as expected, but, as I said, I feel like creating up to 49 notifications at once, when there is a pending notification limit for iOS of 64 as stated [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#ios-pending-notifications-limit)(and apparently 500 for [Samsung](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduled-android-notifications)) isn't really efficient and I am almost certain I am missing something here.

So what is the proper way to do this ?

Comment: I would also greatly appreciate some help on this. I'm working on a reminder app that could have 1 minute intervals. If a user sets a reminder every minute for 8 hours (or anything equivalent) that already exceeds the limit on all platforms. Currently I'm using flutter_local_notifications and setting a hard limit for notifications (differs for each platform). 

I was thinking maybe setting one notification at a time, and when that notification is triggered, it schedules the one after it?

Any ideas or solutions would be very welcome!

Comment: Hi, you might want to take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager. 
There are some tutorials on youtube on how to set up notifications with the workmanager package.